# Как подставить текст в текстовые поля WebView?

Tags: ios, swift

Я создаю переменные username и password, которые берут значения из TextField'ов, передаю их во вторую форму с WKWebView, в котором открывается страница авторизации сайта, например, ВК. Как подставить username и password в соответствующие поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Посмотрите примеры с использованием фреймворка Apple, JavaScriptCore
2. Или, в случае ВК, используйте их SDK для подстановки